# Short exact sequence for topological join: split needed

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

I am desperately trying to solve the following problem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $X * Y$ their join. Prove that there is a short exact sequence
$$ 0 \to \tilde{H}_k(X * Y) \to \tilde{H}_{k-1}(X \times Y) \to \tilde{H}_{k-1}(X) \oplus \tilde{H}_{k-1}(Y) \to 0$$
Using Mayer-Vietoris it was quite easy to show, that there is a long exact sequence of that fashion. I only need to "cut" it in the right way, to get the short exact sequence. The two things I already figured out:

1. The second map is $\phi := (p_1)_* \oplus (p_2)_*$, where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the projections $X \times Y \to X$, $X \times Y \to Y$.
2. The most elegant way to prove this is providing a split $$s : \tilde{H}_{k-1}(X) \oplus \tilde{H}_{k-1}(Y) \to \tilde{H}_{k-1}(X \times Y)$$ with $ {\rm id} = ( (p_1)_* \oplus (p_2)_*)\circ s$.

My approach: Choose $x_0 \in X, y_0 \in Y$ and define $\iota_X : X \to X \times Y$ by $x \mapsto (x,y_0)$ and $\iota_Y$ analogously. Let $s := (\iota_X)_* + (\iota_Y)_*$.
If I am not mistaken we now get
$$\phi \circ s \big( [\sigma], [\rho]\big) = \Big( [\sigma] + \big[\rm const _{x_0}\big] , [\rho] + \big[\rm const_{y_0}\big]\Big)$$
So only $\big[\rm const _{x_0}\big] =0$ remains to be proven. This is the point where I am stuck. I think I'm overlooking something, because this looks like it should be obvious to me, but it isn't …

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It might help to know that $X * Y \simeq \Sigma(X \wedge Y)$ (the join is homotopy equivalent to the suspension of the smash product).

Comment: In odd degrees the degenerate constant chain is the boundary of the 1 level higher degenerate constant chain; In even degrees the constant chain is not a cycle, so the original $\sigma$ must not be a simplex; rather it should be a linear combination that gives you an even number of $[y_0]$ when projected onto Y.